# Algorithm for computing square roots.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Fix a positive number $\alpha$. Choose $x_1>\sqrt{\alpha}$ and define $x_2, x_3, x_4, \dots$ by the recursion formula $$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(x_n+\frac{\alpha}{x_n}\right).$$It's easy to check that $\{x_n\}$ decreases monotonically and $x_n\to\sqrt{\alpha}$.

Put $\varepsilon_n=x_n-\sqrt{\alpha}$ and we get $\varepsilon_{n+1}=\dfrac{\varepsilon_n^2}{2x_n}<\dfrac{\varepsilon_n^2}{2\sqrt{\alpha}}$ so that, setting $\beta=2\alpha,$ $$\varepsilon_{n+1}<\beta\left(\frac{\varepsilon_1}{\beta}\right)^{2^n} \qquad(*)$$

Am I true that formula $(*)$ shows the rapidity of convergence of above prove?

What about if $x_1>3\sqrt{\alpha}$? Because in this case $$\frac{\varepsilon_1}{\beta}=\frac{x_1-\sqrt{\alpha}}{2\sqrt{\alpha}}>\frac{2\sqrt{\alpha}}{2\sqrt{\alpha}}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

Your (*) inequality is not contradictory with $\frac{\epsilon_1}{\beta}>1$ for $x_1 > 3\sqrt{\alpha}$.

It just means that the convergence is as fast as (*) for $x_n$ close enough to $\sqrt{\alpha}$.

Comment: I think that you didn't understand my question. If $x_1>3\sqrt{\alpha}$ then $\dfrac{\varepsilon_1}{\beta}>1$ but you wrote that is equal to $1$. In this case $\left(\frac{\varepsilon_1}{\beta}\right)^{2^n}\to \infty$. Yeah it's not contadictory but this inequality in this case doesn't give any information about rapidity of convergence.

Comment: $\epsilon_{n+1}$ is less than something growing to infinity. This is not an issue. As an example you have $\frac{1}{n} \le n$ and $n \to +\infty$. It doesn't prevent to have $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$.